# Convert a text to JSON

Tags: ruby, json

I have a text file say data.txt which contains content of format:

```
( {
city = Leesburg;
country = USA;
dob = "";
email = "email@domain.com";
firstName = "EricM.";
homePhone = "";
lastName = Abcdef;
mobilePhone = 12312312;
state = Virginia;
workPhone = 12312312;
},
 {
city = "Mt. Uncle";
dob = "";
email = "";
firstName = first;
homePhone = "";
lastName = Berry;
mobilePhone = 234234;
state = MD;
workPhone = "";
}
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this file? Do you want to parse it with Ruby? Do you want to manually edit it to become JSON? Where is this file coming from?

Comment: This simplest thing is that I have it, and I need to create a Valid JSON from it.

Comment: If you only need to create JSON from this file and of no other files, then the easiest is to do it by hand!

Comment: File is large and has 4000 entries

Comment: See my answer, should work for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

```
require "json"

file = File.open("data.txt")

contents = file.read

hashes = contents.scan(/{(.*?)}/mx)

arr = []
hashes.each do |hash|
    hashitems = hash[0].scan(/(\w+\s=\s.+?);/)
    ahash = {}
    hashitems.each do |hashitem|
        itemarr = hashitem[0].split(" = ")
        ahash[itemarr[0]] = itemarr[1]
    end
    arr << ahash
end

print JSON.dump(arr)
```

What I've done here is use two regex functions to break down your data into a Ruby object, then I've used the JSON library to dump the object to JSON.